# Horror Movie where a child had to hide his hands and feet under the bed cover to avoid being caught by a monster

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I am searching for the title of a horror movie, which I never saw the end of. As far as I could remember, a brother has to babysit his younger brother, because the parents were out. The younger brother was scared, because there was a monster which he said about, caught him, when he didn't hide under his bed cover completely. The older brother didn't believe what the younger was saying.

Later, the older brother had a girlfriend in the house, too and they fight against this monster I think. There also was a scene, in which he and his girlfriend were standing in a hallway in the house and a face came out through a wall.

I've seen it on TV in the mid 2000 I think. Maybe, it was a free TV premiere at this time.

Comment: You have a nice start here but could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, when did you watch this? Was it new at the time? What did the monster look like? etc.

Comment: Horror movie? That's just good common sense.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite precisely! This isn't a movie plot, it's my nightly sleep routine :D

Answer (score 2):

This is [Fear of the Dark](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0308252/) from 2003.

> **Twelve year old Ryan Billings has been diagnosed with an acute fear of the dark. He spends each night lying awake in torment**, waiting and watching as the evil in the darkness grows stronger, feeding off his fear. **His older brother Dale, suspects that there is nothing wrong with Ryan and that this is just a ploy for more attention. Regardless, he promises to watch over his little brother as their parents head off to a party for the night.** Outside a storm rages and when the power goes out, darkness envelops the house. Ryan knows that tonight the evil has finally come to claim him. Dale desperately tries everything to try and calm him down, until the horrors in the dark make him realize Ryan had good reason to be so afraid!

Dale's girlfriend is there too and at some point a ghostly face (& hands) emerge from a hallway wall. The film's currently available on Youtube. Here's the trailer: